# Reference a dynamic variable inside a sting

Tags: php, variables

i have the following in PHP

```
$userid = 23;

$redirect = "Hello user, $userid";
```

in the middle of my code, i do this:

```
$userid = 56;

$warning = $redirect;
```

the output of the variable $warning is the following:

```
Hello user, 23
```

but i want to be this

```
Hello user, 56
```

I know the solution is to reassign it again, like so

```
$warning = "Hello user, $labelid";
```

But i was wondering if there was another way of going about this without reassinging?

Comment: The first string already gets assigned with "Hello user, 23" So on the second time it won't get replaced again. You have to reassign it

Comment: so, there is no other way, no tricks or else...

Comment: Not really, you could place a placeholder instead of the variable name in the string and if you assign it just use the variable to replace the placeholder. But that's pretty much the same

Answer (score 1):

You can have "template" string that gets interpolated ([sprintf](https://php.net/sprintf)) when needed.

```
$helloString = "Hello user, %d";
```

and then

```
$userId = 23;
$redirect = sprintf($helloString, $userId);
```

and

```
$userId = 56;
$warning = sprintf($helloString, $userId);
```

also in your example you use `$userid` for variable, yet  there is `$labelid` in the string; I'm using this is error.